# Ubuntu 23.04 Fails to Install At same point each time

Tags: system-installation, 23.04

Standard Ubuntu 23.04 with the new installer fails every time it gets to the point where it needs to install Ubuntu-Restricted_Extras. Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS installs just fine. I'm at a loss of what to do. Maybe another set of eyes can spot something I don't see.

[image: Installation Failed]